# extract tar file from s3 and and update it back to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, tar

I have a file in s3 example.tar , i need to untar it and save it back to s3 using aws cli commands. i tried this

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/ex.tar -| tar xvf --to-command='aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/$TAR_REALNAME'

tar: Cannot connect to --to-command=aws s3 cp - s3: resolve failed
download failed: s3://webtable06/06.tar to - [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: This might help: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).